# set own element id (or at least part of it) in gwt treeitem

Tags: gwt

our selenium test are based on "gwt-debug-ids" - if i want to identify an element i set the id via uibinder or ensureDebugId method. But this fails on treeitems. it seems that gwt generates own ids for each treeitem. `ensureDebugId("id")` and `getElement.setId("id")` doesn't work.
i guess the ids are generated on render time?! 
in my case each tree item is associated with a data object with its own id. i need the treeitem id to be my own id or at least this id must be a part of the resulting id.

how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

In the [GWT documentation](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TreeItem.html) it says:

*An item that can be contained within a Tree. Each tree item is assigned a unique DOM id in order to support ARIA. See Accessibility for more information.*

ARIA stands for [Accessible Rich Internet Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAI-ARIA) a specification for making web applications accessible via a standard set of DOM attributes.

Comment: adding an prefix or suffix won't break the uniqueness?! but with it i could selenium test the tree.